# Coverage fatal error (EclEmma)

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, eclipse-plugin, code-coverage

I am using Eclipse Mars 4.5.2. When running coverage tests for my application, which has 317 test methods so far, when it's about to finish (around 274 methods run), I am getting errors I can't find a solution to.

First a popup window saying:

> No Coverage Data
>
> No coverage data has been collected during this
>   coverage session.
>
> Please do not terminate the Java process manually
>   from Eclipse.

A secon popup window:

> 'com.mountainminds.eclemma.internal.core.launching.AgentServer' has
>   encountered a problem. Error while dumping coverage date (code 5013).
>
> [Details:] 
>   Error while dumping coverage data (code 5013). Connection
>   reset

And then the following console log:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005f9b96af, pid=2024, tid=3772
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_66-b18) (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b18 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>   Problematic frame:
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x4b96af]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   X:\xxxxx\hs_err_pid2024.log
>
> Compiler replay data is saved as:
>   X:\xxxxx\replay_pid2024.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

I have been suffering this issue for a couple of weeks and, as I said, I can't find any solution, just similar bug reports in the EclEmma site from four or five years ago.

I have tried setting the following JVM arguments for JUnit: `-Xms2g -Xmx2g`.

My tests don't have any database connection, server connection nor network connection. They don't make any HTTP request either.

I have tried reinstalling the EclEmma plugin as well as reinstalling Eclipse. The issue persisted.

Comment: Please provide the complete crash log

Answer (score 1):

Update the coverage configuration. Go to the Arguments section and add below perm size argument in VM arguments section:
-XX:MaxPermSize=1225m

Comment: VM arg for permsize no longer supported past java 8. It uses metaspace now

Answer (score 0):

From Eclipcse help:

**If the Java VM is killed externally, e.g. with theEclipse Terminate action, coverage results can not be shown**

snip:

> Coverage Data Collection
>
> Coverage data is collected and presented automatically when the
> applicationterminates on its own. **If the Java VM is killed
> externally, e.g. with theEclipse Terminate action, coverage results
> can not be shown**. Inaddition intermediate coverage data dumps can
> also be requested from anyprocess running in Coverage mode. Such dumps
> can be triggered from thetoolbar of the Coverage view.